# Nextjs project crashes and needs a refresh when i switch tabs in browser

Tags: next.js, browser, tabs, crash, hydration

I am using nextjs 14. It works perfectly fine when i first run it. But after i switch to another tab in the browser and spend some time there then go back to the project tab, the project is crashed and needs a refresh to be fixed. What can cause this issue?